# ReactJS giving error Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__... is undefined when implementing Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-context

I'm using **Context API** for a cryptocurrency tracker app. What I want is to create the state `currency` and `setCurrency` from the context named `CryptoState` which I created in **CryptoContext.js** and import to **Header** component so I can use them to do the function `onChange`. When I import state from `CryptoState` it has the error as in the title and causes the page emptied.

Here's my code:

**CryptoContext.js**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Crypto = createContext()

const CryptoContext = ({ children }) => {

  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("VND")
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("₫")

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currency === "VND") setSymbol("₫")
    else if (currency === "USD") setSymbol("$")
  }, [currency])

  return (
    <Crypto.Provider value={{currency, symbol, setCurrency}}>{children}</Crypto.Provider>
  )
}

export default CryptoContext

export const CryptoState = () => {
  return useContext(Crypto)
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import { 
  AppBar, 
  Container, 
  Toolbar, 
  Typography, 
  Select, 
  MenuItem,
} from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { CryptoState } from '../CryptoContext'

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  title: {
    flex: 1,
    color: 'gold',
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    cursor: 'pointer'
  }
}))

const Header = () => {

  const classes = useStyles()

  const { currency, setCurrency } = CryptoState()

  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: '#fff',
      },
      type: 'dark'
    }
  })
  
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <AppBar color="transparent" position="static">
        <Container>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography 
              className={classes.title}
              variant='h6'
            >
              <Link to="/"> 
                Crypto Hunter
              </Link>
            </Typography>

            <Select 
              variant="outlined"
              style={{
                width: 100,
                height: 40,
                marginRight: 15,
              }}
              defaultValue={'VND'}
              value={currency}
              onChange={(e) => setCurrency(e.target.value)}
            >
              <MenuItem value={"USD"}>USD</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"VND"}>VND</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default Header
```

As soon as I import the state by this line: `const { currency, setCurrency } = CryptoState()` in **Header.js**, it causes error `TypeError: _CryptoContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.CryptoState() is undefined` and cause the page emptied.

Here's the captured image of the error: [error's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xd1g.jpg)

All answers are highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### **Hey Guys so i was having this error below**

[image]

The main issue is just to make sure your naming convention for exporting your useContext must be in camelCase Naming convention and make sure your index.js is wrapped around with your Context provider.

*so instead of this*

```js
export const UseStateContext = () => {
    return useContext(StateContext);
};
```

**DO THIS!!!**

```js
export const useStateContext = () => {
    return useContext(StateContext);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong now.

1. Try to rename `CryptoContext` to `CryptoProvider`.
2. Where does Header is render? in App.js?
3. Please find out where is contain  and wrap the Provider of `CryptoProvider`:

```
<CryptoProvider>
  <Header />
</CryptoProvider>
```

4. In `Header.js` component. You have to use the variable you set for `createContext` function. then, please use `useContext` instead of calling it directly

```
// CryptoContext.js

const cryptoContext = createContext(); // remember to export this var.
```

Then, in `Header.js`

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { cryptoContext } from './CryptoContext';

const { currency, setCurrency } = useContext(cryptoContext);
```